# RFID Limitations

Tags: rfid, time-and-attendance, technical-debt

my graduate project is about Smart Attendance System for University using RFID.
What if one student have multiple cards (cheating) and he want to attend his friend as well? The situation here my system will not understand the human adulteration and it will attend the detected RFID Tags by the reader and the result is it will attend both  students and it will store them in the database.

I am facing this problem from begging and it is a huge glitch in my system.

I need a solution or any idea for this problem and it can be implemented in the code or in the real live to identify the humans.

Comment: which frequency are you working with ? Are those UHF, HF, LF? Do you have physical limitations or can use another hardware as well ?

Comment: I'm using UHF with 15 Meter Range my University give me this hardware only and the want to solve this problem, any advice ?

Comment: You could place a display with the number of total attendance, and the professor has to count the students. If the numbers doesn't match, just go for the old way he was doing it and found out which student was cheating. Still, we all are giving you working-around solutions. If you want pure HW/SW answers, they would be very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could do this depending upon your dedication, the exact tech available to you, and the consistency of the environment you are working with.  Here are the first two that come to mind:

1)  Create a grid of reader antennae on the ceiling of your room and use signal response times to the three nearest readers to get a decent level of confidence as to where the student tag is.  If two tags register as being too close, display the associated names for the professor to call out and confirm presence.  This solution will be highly dependent upon the precision of your equipment and stability of temperature/humidity in the room (and possibly other things like liquid and metal presence).

2)  Similar to the first solution, but a little different.  Some readers and tags (Impinj R2000 and Indy Readers, Impinj Monza 5+ for sure, maybe others aswell) have the ability to report a response time and a phase angle associated with the signal received from an interrogated tag.  Using a set up similar to the first, you can get a much higher level of reliability and precision if you use this method.

Answer (score 0):

Your software could randomly pick a few names of attending people, so that the professor can ask them to identify themselves. This will not eliminate the possibility of cheating, but increase the risk of beeing caught.

Other idea: count the number of attendiees (either by the prof or by camera + SW) and compare that to the number of RfID tags visible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for this RFID limitation.

But if you could then you can use Biometric(fingerprint) recognition facility with RFID card. With this in your system you have to:

1. Integrate biometric scanner with your RFID reader
2. Store biometric data in your card

and while making attendance :

1. Read UID
2. Scan biometric by student
3. Match scanned biometric with your stored biometric(in the card :
   step 2)
4. Make attendance (present if biometric matched, absent if no match)

Comment: why bother with RFID if you have a fingerprint scanner?

Answer (score 0):

Well, We all have that glitch, and you can do nothing about it, but with the help of a camera system, i think it would minimise this glitch.

why use a camera system and not a biometric fingerprint system? lets re-phrase the question, why use RFID if there is biometric fingerprint system ? ;)

what is ideal to use, is an RFID middleware that handle the tag reading.

once the reader detects a tag, the middleware simply call the security camera system and request for a snapshot, and store it in the db. I'm using an RFID middleware called Envoy.